# oracle db from keyword not found where expected in double cte

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a double `cte` expression , the first one `join` two tables and the second is implementing a `partition by` function:

```
with cte as (
  select * 
  from memuat.product p
  join memuat.licence l on p.id = l.product_id
  where l.managed = 'TRUE'
),
joined as (
  select
    *,
    row_number() over (partition by id order by id) as rn
  from cte
)
select * from joined;
```

I get the following error:

> ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected, ERROR at line 12.
> I cannot figure out which syntax error is wrong in my query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle is nitpicking when it comes to `SELECT *`. `SELECT *` means "select everything", so how can you possibly add something to it? In Oracle you cannot `SELECT *, 1 AS something_else FROM some_table`. You must have `SELECT some_table.*, 1 AS something_else FROM some_table`, so you are no longer selecting "everything", but "everything from the table" :-)

You have

```
select
  *,
  row_number() over (partition by id order by id) as rn
from cte
```

It must be

```
select
  cte.*,
  row_number() over (partition by id order by id) as rn
from cte
```

instead.

Comment: oh yes, I guess other rdbms don't complain about that. but you're right my query works now